# Iterating over member typed collection fails when using untyped reference to generic object

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generics in for each loop problem if instance does not have generic type assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316095/generics-in-for-each-loop-problem-if-instance-does-not-have-generic-type-assigne)

Could someone clarify why `iterate1()` is not accepted by compiler (Java 1.6)? I do not see why `iterate2()` and `iterate3()` are much better.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test<T> {

    public Collection<String> getCollection() {
        return new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public void iterate1(Test test) {
        for (String s : test.getCollection()) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void iterate2(Test test) {
        Collection<String> c = test.getCollection();
        for (String s : c) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void iterate3(Test<?> test) {
        for (String s : test.getCollection()) {
            // ...
        }
    }


}
```

Compiler output:

```
$ javac Test.java
Test.java:11: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
  for (String s : test.getCollection()) {
                                              ^
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Comment: Should `public Collection<String> getCollection()` be `public Collection<T> getCollection()`? I don't have my compiler available ATM to test the difference between these two.

Comment: Answered in a discussion here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316095/generics-in-for-each-loop-problem-if-instance-does-not-have-generic-type-assigne

Comment: No, my intention is to use Collection<String>. I just do not understand why I cannot do it if I use non-typed reference to class.

Comment: @Arham Excellent. Key phrase from that question: "If you use the raw type (which you shouldn't) the compiler will erase **all** generic information for that instance even if it's not the type parameter T, to make it compatible with pre 1.5 code."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use a raw type (e.g. `Test` rather than `Test<T>`, the compiler treats it ([JLS 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)) as the *erasure* of that type ([JLS 4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)) - that erases generics completely, whether they use the type parameter or not:

> The type parameters of a constructor or method (§8.4.4), and the return type (§8.4.5) of a method, also undergo erasure if the constructor or method's signature is erased.

Basically, the use of a raw type is treated by the compiler as an indication that you don't want that code to be aware of generics at all - so the method signature is erased to:

```
public Collection getCollection()
```

... hence the compile-time error, as the inferred element type is `Object`, as per [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Comment: Now I understood difference between iterate1() and iterate3(). However, still do not understand difference between iterate1() and iterate2().

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: I'd expect `iterate2()` to give a warning about generic type safety, and Xlint to show an unchecked conversion from `Collection` to `Collection<String>`.

Comment: Yes, it gives. But it is not clear why it gives error in iterate1() and warning in iterate2(). I use raw type in both methods  so generics should be erased.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: Because in `iterate2()` you're explicitly assigning a raw type to a generic type (`Collection<String>`) first. That's an unchecked conversion, but it's a valid one.